# Why get_terms() behaves strangely when being called in admin (for use in meta box)?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms, parameter

I encountered a problem trying to make a select button comprising options of custom post type taxonomies (terms, taxonomies, not sure about proper nomenclature?).

So, the function:

```
$terms = get_terms(array(
    "hide_empty" => false,
));

foreach ($terms as $term) {

    echo "<li>".$term->name."</li>";
}
```

Whenever I call the function without stating "taxonomy" parameter (plain function, as above) it's working fine displaying all Wordpress taxonomies **including those for my custom post type**.

When I include `"taxonomy" => "category"` in get_terms() arguments array it gives me list of native post categories, for `"taxonomy" => "post_tag"` it displays all pos tags names but when I change it to `"taxonomy" => "my_custom_taxonomy"` (which is being displayed just fine among other taxonomies when I don't include `"taxonomy"` parameter at all, just as I mentioned above) it returns `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\........php on line xx`

Why is it happening and is there a simple workaround to this?

All help will be much apprieciated! Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing the full error, it's hard to say, but keep in mind that the code assumes terms were found and never checks if `$terms` is empty or an error object

Comment: Sorry, I didn't highlight the full error. Dots in the error is just the path to .php file and two xs are the line number where the error occurs.

Comment: What's in that file at that location? You shouldn't trivialise/ignore PHP warnings and notices when trying to debug things, you're being given a huge clue there! Include the full path, and line number, and what's on the line it mentions

Comment: **@TomJNowell** It's a path to file and line where the above `foreach` loop echoes `$term->name`, there you go: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\archeonew\wp-content\themes\test_theme\inc\admin\meta\profiles_template_meta.php on line 23` and the warning is being displayed twice, one under another.

Comment: Can you check that `$terms` is indeed an array of terms and not an empty array of a `WP_Error` object? `empty()` and `is_wp_error( $terms )` should do the trick

Comment: **@TomJNowell** Whenever I `echo print_r($terms);` I see the array of taxonomies, according to `"taxonomy"` parameter. When "taxonomy" parametes is absent I see all taxonomies **including my custom taxonomy**. When `"taxonomy"` parameter is present and it's value is i.e. `"category"` I see only native post categories, similarily to `"post_tag"` value, when i see only native posts' tags. When I use `"custom_taxonomy" `as a value I get an error as described above which is bugging me.

Comment: hmm you should be seeing an array of WP_Term objects, not taxonomies

Comment: What is the difference? Isn'a a taxonomy a term and vice versa? are post tags terms or taxonomies? Anyway, different things are being displayed depending on "taxonomy" value, just as described above (two times).

Comment: Colour is a taxonomy, red/blue/green are terms. Can you update your question with a full code block with the checks for WP_Error, and that the array is not empty so we're all running the same test? Also your taxonomy registration code. Right now there's only descriptions, and things get lost in translation

Comment: @TomJNowell  That'll be a lot of code, I'll try over the weekend.

Comment: Just the register_taxonomy call and the arguments it takes, and an accompanying `get_terms` loop and checks